# Update session variable with button $_POST

Tags: php, session

I have a working shopping cart where users can enter the quantity of each item in the cart and the page will automatically refresh to ensure the data is kept in the session.

I have a button underneath that users can click on to include or exclude vat in the total price. I'm using jQuery to do this and it works. The problem I have is that when the button is clicked on, it changes from 'Include VAT' to 'Exclude VAT' as per the js but then the button defaults back to its standard 'Include VAT' text on refresh. In other words, I have not yet managed to store the button's state as a session variable or have not yet managed to recall the new version of the variable, or both.

Here's my current attempt...

In shop.php within the form:

```
if (empty($_SESSION['VAT'])){
    $_SESSION['VAT'] = "Include";
}
echo '<button id="togglevat" type="submit" name="vat" class="bodybutton vatbuttons includevat">'.$_SESSION['VAT'].' VAT</button>';
```

And in cart_update.php which is fired whenever the form is submitted, making the page refresh (clicking the VAT button also submits it):

```
$_SESSION['VAT'] = $_POST['vat'];
```

Hope this is enough to go on. Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: So your problem is that, whatever the user does, your buttons keeps its 'include VAT' state after page refreshing, right?

Comment: that's right Sergeon!

Comment: @MarkHolland note: You have an XSS vulnerability in your code, you should always call `htmlspecialchars(string)` to sanitize user input when echoing it back to them

Comment: You're just checking if $_SESSION['VAT'] is empty. Don't you must also check the last vat value or, better, the vat value the user was intending to set when pushing the button?

Comment: Thanks Paradoxis, I'll look into this. Although isn't it ok as the user isn't actually entering any input, just clicking on a button?
Sergeon, the idea is that if the VAT variable has not already been set, it sets it, otherwise it would get it from cart_update.php. Would you be able to explain further what you mean, perhaps with an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a active class

```
button.active{
    background: #bbb;
    border-top: solid 2px #777;
    border-left: solid 2px #777;
    border-bottom:solid 2px  #eaeaea;
    border-right: solid 2px #eaeaea;
}
```

PHP

```
$class = "";
if (empty($_SESSION['VAT'])){
    $_SESSION['VAT'] = "Include";
    $class = "active";
}
echo "<button id='togglevat' type='submit' name='vat' class='bodybutton vatbuttons includevat $class'>".$_SESSION['VAT']." VAT</button>";
```

Comment: thank you for the answer polamaros. Will this enable me to save the text within the button? I think perhaps I wasn't clear on this in my question so I'll edit it. I want the button to change to 'Exclude VAT' when clicked on, which will remain that way even if the page is refreshed until it is clicked on again

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of $_POST['vat'] in cart_update.php?
If you got the value what you needed, then it is the issue of your session variable. You might forgot to start the session.

Comment: Hi Jeram, that's included in cart_update.php so that when the form is submitted the value is passed to the session variable, enabling it to be used when shop.php is refreshed. The session is definitely started so no problem there. Do you have any ideas? Thanks!